# How to use sp_depends for other database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2010

For updating the tables i am using following line

update  database1_ab..table1

For sp_depends i am getting error as "Incorrect syntax near '.'"

sp_depends   database1_ab..table1

How to use sp_depends for referring other database tables in current database

Comment: never heard of SQL Server 2010...

Answer (score 1):

regardless, you need to put it in single quotes... ie

```
sp_depends 'database1_ab..table1'
```

or

```
sp_depends '[database1_ab]..[table1]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call all the sp_ -procedures also in different database like this:

```
database1_ab..sp_depends table1
```